# vTiger 7 mail converter issue with updating Ticket

Tags: php, mysql, vtiger

Having an issue with Mail Converter and updating tickets, from what I can tell its failing on a query that is missing a linked table, after turning on debugging and running the Mail Converter this is the query that it is returning:

> INFO VT - PearDatabase ->ADODB error Query Failed:SELECT
>   vtiger_troubletickets.ticket_no AS
>   vtiger_troubleticketsticket_no,vtiger_crmentity.smownerid AS
>   vtiger_crmentityassigned_user_id,vtiger_troubletickets.parent_id AS
>   vtiger_troubleticketsparent_id,vtiger_troubletickets.status AS
>   vtiger_troubleticketsticketstatus,vtiger_crmentity.createdtime AS
>   vtiger_crmentitycreatedtime,vtiger_crmentity.modifiedtime AS
>   vtiger_crmentitymodifiedtime,vtiger_crmentity.modifiedby AS
>   vtiger_crmentitymodifiedby,vtiger_troubletickets.title AS
>   vtiger_troubleticketsticket_title,vtiger_crmentity.description AS
>   vtiger_crmentitydescription,vtiger_troubletickets.solution AS
>   vtiger_troubleticketssolution,vtiger_troubletickets.contact_id AS
>   vtiger_troubleticketscontact_id,vtiger_ticketcf.from_portal AS
>   vtiger_ticketcffrom_portal,vtiger_crmentity.smcreatorid AS
>   vtiger_crmentitycreated_user_id,vtiger_ticketcf.cf_779 AS
>   vtiger_ticketcfcf_779,vtiger_ticketcf.cf_781 AS
>   vtiger_ticketcfcf_781,vtiger_ticketcf.cf_787 AS
>   vtiger_ticketcfcf_787,vtiger_ticketcf.cf_791 AS
>   vtiger_ticketcfcf_791,vtiger_ticketcf.cf_805 AS
>   vtiger_ticketcfcf_805,vtiger_ticketcf.cf_811 AS
>   vtiger_ticketcfcf_811,vtiger_crmentity.cf_viewname AS
>   vtiger_crmentitycf_viewname,vtiger_ticketcf.cf_910 AS
>   vtiger_ticketcfcf_910,vtiger_ticketcf.cf_916 AS
>   vtiger_ticketcfcf_916,vtiger_ticketcf.cf_920 AS
>   vtiger_ticketcfcf_920,vtiger_ticketcf.cf_922 AS
>   vtiger_ticketcfcf_922,vtiger_ticketcf.cf_924 AS
>   vtiger_ticketcfcf_924,vtiger_ticketcf.cf_934 AS
>   vtiger_ticketcfcf_934,vtiger_ticketcf.cf_936 AS
>   vtiger_ticketcfcf_936,vtiger_ticketcf.cf_938 AS
>   vtiger_ticketcfcf_938,vtiger_ticketcf.cf_940 AS
>   vtiger_ticketcfcf_940,vtiger_ticketcf.cf_942 AS
>   vtiger_ticketcfcf_942,vtiger_ticketcf.cf_944 AS
>   vtiger_ticketcfcf_944,vtiger_ticketcf.cf_950 AS
>   vtiger_ticketcfcf_950,vtiger_ticketcf.cf_966 AS
>   vtiger_ticketcfcf_966,vtiger_ticketcf.cf_968 AS
>   vtiger_ticketcfcf_968,vtiger_ticketcf.cf_970 AS
>   vtiger_ticketcfcf_970,vtiger_ticketcf.cf_972 AS
>   vtiger_ticketcfcf_972,vtiger_ticketcf.cf_974 AS
>   vtiger_ticketcfcf_974,vtiger_ticketcf.cf_976 AS
>   vtiger_ticketcfcf_976,vtiger_ticketcf.cf_978 AS
>   vtiger_ticketcfcf_978,vtiger_ticketcf.cf_980 AS
>   vtiger_ticketcfcf_980,vtiger_ticketcf.cf_986 AS
>   vtiger_ticketcfcf_986,vtiger_crmentity.source AS
>   vtiger_crmentitysource,vtiger_helpdesk_user_field.starred AS
>   vtiger_helpdesk_user_fieldstarred,vtiger_troubletickets.tags AS
>   vtiger_troubleticketstags,vtiger_crmentity.deleted,
>   vtiger_crmentity.label FROM vtiger_crmentity LEFT JOIN
>   vtiger_troubletickets ON (vtiger_troubletickets.ticketid =
>   vtiger_crmentity.crmid ) LEFT JOIN vtiger_ticketcf ON
>   (vtiger_ticketcf.ticketid = vtiger_crmentity.crmid ) LEFT JOIN
>   vtiger_ticketcomments ON (vtiger_ticketcomments.ticketid =
>   vtiger_crmentity.crmid ) WHERE vtiger_crmentity.crmid=? LIMIT
>   1::->[1054]Unknown column 'vtiger_helpdesk_user_field.starred' in
>   'field list'

You will notice that it is missing the vtiger_helpdesk_user_field table in the FROM list, If i manually run this query adding in the missing table the query runs fine, my question is, is this a bug or can anyone suggest how I would go about fixing this.

Cheers guys.

Answer (score 0):

problem table vtiger_helpdesk_user_field is not created during installation.

Creating this missing table will fix the error and that is the right method